# Set admin date_hierarchy to a ForeignKey date field

Tags: django, django-admin

When I try to set

```
date_hierarchy = "schedule__date"
```

Where schedule is a foreign key.

I get the following error.

```
'TestAdmin.date_hierarchy' refers to field 'schedule__date' that is missing from model 'testing.Test'.
```

I understand the error. What I'm hoping for is that there is some sort of workaround here to allow me to have date_hierarchy from a foreign key date field. I have tried setting a method and propery within the Test model that returns the date and setting that method/property as the date_hierarchy, but no luck.

It seems foolish to have to add another column to my table for the schedule__date when I already have it stored in another table from the foreign key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforturnately, this isn't possible with the current django. The `date_hierarchy` option is explicitly required to be a `DateTimeField` or `DateField`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/admin/checks.py#L837

Comment: No. That code explicitly checks for a datefield on the model itself.

Comment: UPDATE: looks like it is fixed: [PR #6763](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6563)

Answer (score 2):

The ability to reference fields on related models was added in Django 1.11:

> **Minor features**
>
> **django.contrib.admin**
>   ModelAdmin.date_hierarchy can now reference fields across relations.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/