# How to get Django ForeignKey to behave like a DateField

Tags: django, date, foreign-keys, hierarchy

I have a Day class whose ID is a DateField. I have an Event class that links via ForeignKey to that DateField. I'd like to use ModelAdmin features like date_hierarchy but I get

```
<class 'myapp.admin.EventAdmin'>: (admin.E128) 
The value of 'date_hierarchy' must be a DateField or DateTimeField.
```

This is my models.py file:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Day, to_field='date', related_name='events')
    bullet = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bullet[:20]
```

And admin.py has:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date', 'bullet')
    search_fields = ('bullet',)
    list_filter = ('date',)
    date_hierarchy = 'date'
    ordering = ('-date',)
```

date_hierarchy doesn't work, and list_filter doesn't break things down by date.

Is there a way to convert the Event ForeignKey field to a form that's seen as a DateField?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469078/django-models-error-when-using-datefield-as-foreignkey) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102169/set-admin-date-hierarchy-to-a-foreignkey-date-field) unsuccessfully, although a feature coming in v1.11 may let me reference fields on related models directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is a contrived example because single column tables don't make much sense here. You can just as easily have this

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    bullet = models.TextField()
```

Assuming that you have left out some relevent fields and the Day model is important, event should just be:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey(Day, related_name='events')
    bullet = models.TextField()
```

The `to_field` isn't really usefull here. and then

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date__date', 'bullet')
    search_fields = ('bullet',)
    list_filter = ('date__date',)
    date_hierarchy = 'date__date'
    ordering = ('-date__date',)
```

Comment: Strangely, using the double-underscore 'date__date' reference fixed list_filter (it now offers the standard "By Date" box) - but it STILL didn't fix date_hierarchy - Django gave me `<class 'myapp.admin.EventAdmin'>: (admin.E127) The value of 'date_hierarchy' refers to 'date
__date', which is not an attribute of 'myapp.Event'.` Weird. I'm running Django 1.10.5 in this particular virtualenv.

Comment: what's strange about this? it's the standard django notation for referring to related models. But the standard notation does not use spaces in the middle like you have done 'date __date'

Comment: Turned out to be a Django v1.10 issue. I tried 'date__date' in a v1.11 virtualenv, and it worked. v1.11 supports date_hierarchy across relations, as was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102169/set-admin-date-hierarchy-to-a-foreignkey-date-field)